# Duda en comandos de linea con sql

Tags: sql, python

Buenas, estoy tratando de modificar la casilla historia con lo que le ingreso, pero para eso debe coincidir con la cc y fecha, tengo una linea de comando en sql pero no me esta guardando en la base de datos

```
sql="UPDATE Cita set Historias='"+str(AGGH.get())+"' WHERE cc="+str(AGG2.get())+" and fecha="+str(AGG4.get())
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Agrego que estoy manejando python y str(AGG2.get()) son los datos ingresados.
Muchas gracias por su colaboracion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asimiendo que los valores sean varchar en la base de datos te faltaron las comillas:

```
sql="UPDATE Cita set
         Historias = '"+str(AGGH.get())+"'
         WHERE cc  = '"+str(AGG2.get())+"' 
         and fecha = '"+str(AGG4.get())+"';"
```

Comment: Asi me aparece con error, tengo  sql="UPDATE Cita set Historias='"+str(AGGH.get())+"' WHERE cc="+str(AGG2.get())+" and fecha="+str(AGG4.get())     no me aparece sin error pero no me guarda

Comment: ya lo arregle, Funciona?

Comment: no aun no, el punto y coma sobra ya que estoy en python y alli no se maneja

Comment: el punto y coma es para el sql, aveces los necesita, aunque en este caso nopero es buena practica

Comment: se lo coloque y guardo los datos, muchas gracias